# Build x64 project with CefSharp

Tags: c#, 64-bit, cefsharp

I try to compile my app which has CefSharp as dependency. Everything works when targeting x86 but for x64 I get the following error:

```
System.BadImageFormatException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'CefSharp, Version=67.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=40c4b6fc221f4138' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.'
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Here is a screenshot of my configuration settings inside VS 2017,

[image]

and the Project properties' Build tab:

[image]

Comment: `65.0.0` is the current release. Try using an official release instead of an experimental `67` build. Past that there is insufficient detail here to know what's going on.

Comment: @amaitland, Thanks for looking into this. I've built my own version of CEF and CefSharp to support mp3/4. I will provide a screenshof the the Configuration Manager inside Visual Studio 2017 but other than that, what other info I should give?

Comment: the referenced assembly CefSharp should also be build for x64.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Could not load file or assembly 'CefSharp.Wpf for both x64 and x86; only one works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31172045/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-cefsharp-wpf-for-both-x64-and-x86-only-one-wor)

Comment: @dlatikay I've looked at this question but the solution doesn't work for me. I checked the Nuget packages and all seems OK.

Comment: anyway at runtime, there is a clash of bitness. use [corflags](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4947501/1132334) to confirm that the bitness of the referenced dll is 32, if the source code of that is under your control look at the build settings of your CefSharp project.

Comment: Try one of the `CI Builds` from https://www.myget.org/gallery/cefsharp If that works then you've made a mistake somewhere in your build and I really cannot help you with that.

Comment: The solution platform name is irrelevant for C# projects.  There is only one setting that matters and its value is not related to the platform name.  Right-click your EXE project > Properties > Build tab.  You only get 64-bit execution with Platform target = AnyCPU and Prefer 32-bit unticked.  You probably have "Prefer 32-bit" ticked now (the default), so kaboom when it tries to load x64 unmanaged code.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks a lot! This was exactly the problem. Please, put as an answer so I can accept it. Thanks again.

Comment: I lost count of the number of times I had to answer this question.  I think that only saturating Google can avoid it, please add your own version.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hans Passant wrote in the comments:

> The solution platform name is irrelevant for C# projects. There is
>   only one setting that matters and its value is not related to the
>   platform name. Right-click your EXE project > Properties > Build tab.
>   You only get 64-bit execution with Platform target = AnyCPU and Prefer
>   32-bit unticked. You probably have "Prefer 32-bit" ticked now (the
>   default), so kaboom when it tries to load x64 unmanaged code.

That was exactly the problem. Thanks Hans!

Comment: Why is this package not 64-bit capable like every other package out there?

Comment: `CefSharp` supports both `x86` and `x64`. The question is regarding having `AnyCPU` defaulting to `Prefer 32bit` which causes problems as the `x64` unmanaged assemblies cannot be loaded. If you wish to use `AnyCPU` you should see https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/1714